# DBL_MAX integer part equality

Tags: c++, visual-c++, integer, double, max

In Visual C++ 2010, I tried this

```
double d= DBL_MAX;
double dblmaxintpart;
modf(DBL_MAX, &dblmaxintpart);
```

In the debugger window I put

```
d == dblmaxintpart
```

which gave **true** as result.

Can I assume that DBL_MAX is equal to its integer part as an always valid assertion?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the integer part of a `double` which represents an integer will always be the `double` itself, even at `DBL_MAX`. In fact, any `double` greater than 2^52 will have itself as an integer part, because doubles of that size don't have enough mantissal bits to represent a fraction.

For similar reasons, not all integers above 2^53 are representable as `double`s (though when converted to `double`s, they will still be integers).

Finally, the fractional part of any `double` less than 1 will be exactly itself, and the fractional and integer parts of any `double`, when added, will produce exactly the original `double`.

Comment: There are incorrections in your answer: a double is supposed to store the decimal part of a number. How is it possible that "the integer part of a double which represents an integer will ALWAYS be the double itself"? It is even incoherent with your second paragraph. 2^52 ... hmmmm? Isn't that dependent on platform/architecture?

Comment: @sergiol I'm not sure what you're talking about. `double`s are a binary representation, not a decimal representation. As for 2^52, it is not dependent on platform or architecture, but is governed by the IEEE-754 standard.

Comment: Some basic rules: All integers between 0 and 2^53 can be exactly represented as doubles; not all integers greater than 2^53 can be, even if they are less than DBL_MAX. All doubles greater than 2^52 are integers.

Comment: @sergiol It's really important that you understand that IEEE-754 double data type is a binary representation of the number, and not a decimal representation.

Comment: @Ben: That's true of IEEE-754 double-precision floating point.  It's not guaranteed by the C++ Standard.  Compilers may have a `double` data type with more precision that IEEE-754 requires, as long as they define conformance macros in the appropriate way.

Comment: @David: Replace *decimal* by *fractional* -- we know what he meant.  And he's right that the largest non-integral value representable by `double` is platform-dependent.  However, `DBL_MAX` can never have a fractional part.

Comment: @BenVoigt it's true that compilers can increase the precision, so technically I should say 2^(DBL_MANT_DIG-1) and 2^DBL_MANT_DIG. However, I'm not aware of any compilers which define `double` as anything other than binary64, though of course many cheat on flushing extended precision.